# how can i edit the app extension custom keyboard,when use UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton

I want to edit my customKeyboard when I tap the UIButton that in my custom keyboard.
I have already add a UIButton in the keyboard,and the code like this:

```
- (IBAction)resignKeyboardButtonDidTouch:(id)sender {
  [self.view endEditing:YES]; // it doesn’t work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resign keyboard for specific textField like,

```
 [yourTextfield resignFirstResponder];
```

So, try this. You can set same tag to your button and textfield to identify particular textfield.

Comment: how can i get the textField?because I use app extension custom keyboard. the textField in the AViewController,but the exit keyboard button in the BViewController

Comment: but the keyboard is app extension custom keyboard,there are many other app in the iOS,how can i get the textField's tag?